# CMD I need to run a FOR /f on one line of a text file (5th line normally, however this could change depending on return results)

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, command, registry

I have managed to output a query from:

```
REG Query "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall " /F "LanSchool Teacher" /s > %temp%\lanschool.txt
%temp%\lanschool.txt
FOR /F "delims=\" %%a in ('find "%temp%\lanschool.txt) DO ( 
    echo token8=%%h

)
pause
```

However now I have the text file, and it has numerous lines of output in it.

Is it possible to do a:

```
FOR /F "delims=\" %%a in ('find "%temp%\lanschool.txt) DO (
        echo token8=%%h
)
```

But I only want this to run on one line, and that line may change but the only line of that code that I want it to run on, only has one difference compared to another line of code (and that difference is the part of the code that I am trying to get into the `%%h` variable).

The output is this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Teacher
    DisplayName    REG_SZ    LanSchool Teacher

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{89F475EE-2075-4F35-A37D-30C69916EE64}
    DisplayName    REG_SZ    LanSchool Teacher

End of search: 2 match(es) found.
```

I would like to get the `{89F475EE-2075-4F35-A37D-30C69916EE64}` part to be token `%%h` however at the moment as you can see there is 2 REG Keys being output, and the only difference is the part that I want to use, and I can't always guarantee that there will only be 2 REG Keys output.

Sorry if I was all over the place explaining this, let me know if you would like anything clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line should fix it.  It uses `find.exe` to search for the character `{` and if it is not found then the file will not be created, so you can branch on that.

```
REG Query "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall " /F "LanSchool Teacher" /s |find "{" > %temp%\lanschool.txt
if not exist %temp%\lanschool.txt goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks you are a true genious!

Answer (score 0):

would

```
for /f "tokens=2delims=}{" %%a in (
 'REG Query "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall " /F LanSchool Teacher" /s'
 ) do set mystring={%%a}
echo %mystring%
```

work for you?

Comment: Sorry only just got back to my computer, I tested the other script here first and it worked, so I am not sure if this worked or not, but thank you very much for your input.